# Fragment Navigation - IllegalStateException view.findViewById() must not be null

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to navigate to second page of my app. But while I'm trying I get this error everytime and It crash as well. "java.lang.IllegalStateException: view.restaurantRecycler.…dViewById(R.id.restImage) must not be null". I'm using 2 fragments right now. First one is restaurant list that shows nearby 5 restaurants. Second page gonna be details of a restaurant that clicked on first page. But i can't even navigate without perceive which restaurant is clicked.

Here is my code on first fragment : **// part is where i get my error and restImage is inside the recyclerView

```
class RestaurantListPage : Fragment() {

    lateinit var fusedLocationClient : FusedLocationProviderClient
    val PERMISSION_ID = 1010
    lateinit var myViewModel: MainViewModel
    private val restaurantAdapter = RestaurantAdapter(arrayListOf())

    companion object {
        var lat: Double = 0.0
        var lon: Double = 0.0
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireActivity())

        if (checkLocationPermission()){
            getLatLong()
        }


        observeResponseData()


    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_restaurant_list_page, container, false)

        val recyclerView : RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.restaurantRecycler)
        recyclerView.adapter = restaurantAdapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        **//view.restaurantRecycler.restImage.setOnClickListener { Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.goToDetailPage) }**

        return view
    }


    private fun getLatLong(){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {

            return
        }
        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location ->
            if(location != null) {
                lat = location.latitude
                lon = location.longitude
                myViewModel.callApi(lat,lon)

            }
        }
    }


    private fun observeResponseData(){
        myViewModel.liveNearbyRestaurants.observe(this, Observer {
                data -> data?.let { restaurantAdapter.updateRestaurants(it) }
        })

        myViewModel.liveLoading.observe(this, Observer {
                isLoading -> isLoading?.let {
            progress_bar.visibility = if(it) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
        }
        })
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        when (requestCode) {
            PERMISSION_ID -> {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if ((grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            requireActivity(),
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    ) {

                        getLatLong()
                    }
                } else {
                    // permission denied, Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                return
            }
        }
        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }

    private fun checkLocationPermission(): Boolean {
        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        ) {
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    requireActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                )
            ) {
                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    requireActivity(),
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                    PERMISSION_ID
                )
            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    requireActivity(),
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                    PERMISSION_ID
                )
            }
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you include the code of your `fragment_restaurant_list_page.xml` and `RestaurantAdapter.kt`? I can't imagine what `restaurantRecycler.restImage` could be. If that is supposed to be an image of a single restaurant item in your list, then you should access it from the layout of the restaurant item.

Comment: if restImage is the part of your recycler adapter, then you need to setup an interface which will communicate with the fragment, because for me view.restaurantRecycler.restImage this is looking unsettling. Can you add your xml file, and if possible your adapter as well .